# "Вшивка" файлов перевода Qt в исполняемый файл

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Пишу статическую программу, с использованием графической библиотеки Qt, и столкнулся с проблемой перевода стандартных графических элементов.

Приложению требуется .qm файл для перевода стандартных элементов, таких как QColorDialog и QButtonBox (в моем случае).

Но крайне хотелось бы, чтобы программа была полностью статической, т.е. был только один exe-шник, без каких-либо дополнительных файлов. Но в таком случае отсутствует перевод этих элементов на форме. И если QButtonBox можно заменить на обычные кнопки, то самому делать ColorDialog из-за такого не очень хочется.

При этом язык у программы всего один - русский - и нет нужды в динамическом его изменении.

Так вот вопрос в том, можно ли как-нибудь вшить этот файл с переводом в exe-шник программы или применить перевод к элементам не в run-time-е, а в compile-time-е?

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить файлы перевода (*.qm) в файлы ресурсов.

> применить перевод к элементам не в run-time-е

Перевод с помощью метода `load` класса `QTranslator` и так выполняется в run-time.

Шаги:

1) В проекте создать файл ресурсов Qt (*.qrc).

2) В файле ресурсов добавить префикс «/» (без кавычек).

3) К префиксу «/» добавить файлы *.qm

Пример кода:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QTranslator translator;
translator.load(":/Translations/my_translate_" + QLocale::system().name());
a.installTranslator(&translator);

MainWindow w;
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://bravikov.wordpress.com/2016/11/02/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-qt/), [здесь](https://evileg.com/ru/post/153/) и в самой [документации QT](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtranslator.html).

Comment: Да, действительно, совсем забыл про файлы ресурсов, спасибо. Отмечу только (вдруг кому пригодится), что для перевода стандартных элементов нужен не один файл qt_ru.qm, а комплект файлов из директории translations в каталоге с Qt. Все эти файлы заносятся в ресурсы и приложение их спокойно видит. В функции load подключается только файл qt_ru.qm, а он уже в свою очередь использует остальные.

Comment: Вы пересобирали qt, чтобы иметь возможность статической сборки?

Comment: Да, собирал себе Qt 5.5 msvc-2010 и mingw-4.9.2 в статике.